# Как ограничить длину автогенерируемых данных в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я создаю таблицу с автогенерируемым набором данных. И мне нужно, чтобы данные были созданы с ограничением по длине.

вот такой запрос, выдаст ошибку

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries(
                                  country_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                  country_name varchar(10),
                                  continent varchar(10),
                                  code varchar(2)
);

INSERT INTO countries(country_id, country_name, continent, code)
SELECT country_id,
       md5(random()::varchar(10)),
       md5(random()::varchar(10)),
       md5(random()::varchar(2))
FROM generate_series(1,100) country_id;
```

Следующий запрос отработает четко, но не будут соблюдена длина автогенерируемых данных.

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries(
                                  country_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                  country_name text,
                                  continent text,
                                  code text
);

INSERT INTO countries(country_id, country_name, continent, code)
SELECT country_id,
       md5(random()::varchar(10)),
       md5(random()::varchar(10)),
       md5(random()::varchar(2))
FROM generate_series(1,100) country_id;
```

Как это исправить ?

Comment: select md5(random()::varchar(10))::varchar(10)
?

Comment: А какой великий смысл ограничивать результат работы RANDOM()? `md5(random()::text)::varchar(10)`. A `random()::varchar(2)` так и вовсе будет всегда возвращать `'0.'`

Comment: смысл в том, чтобы таблицу наполнить тестовыми данными определенный величины. Я думал это из контекста и так понятно.